# iframe above main html

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am trying to build a simple HTML test where an iframe is covering up elements from the main HTML so it won't be visible.
I configured the iframe to be 100% height and width but it seems like the main HTML is still viewing it's elements within the page.

This is the main HTML:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<style>
html, body, iframe {
margin:0; /* remove any margins of the IFrame and the body tag */
padding:0;
height:100%; /* set height 100% so that it fills the entire view port*/
}

.iframe {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
.main {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position:absolute;
z-index:10000000;
}
</style>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div class=main>
<iframe src="iframe.html" width=100% height=100%></iframe>
</div>
<p>Test is after the iframe</p>
</body>
</HTML>
```

I would like for the "Test is after the iframe" text to not appear as it should be under the iframe that takes 100% of the page.

A screenshot of how it currently looks:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeking to place an iframe "above" the current page contents you can make use of z-index and position the iframe as absolute as follows.

```
position: absolute;
z-index: 9999;
```

Another option(Which would probably look better and offer more control) would be to use something like lightbox or fancybox(JS libs). This would allow you to dynamically control how the html is covered and allow you to place the iframe code inside of each instance offering more control.

Comment: I've added position and z-index to the iframe CSS and it still does not work

Comment: Possibly provide us a link, this will help us debug what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

First, get rid of the div around the iframe, as that's not required.

```
<iframe src="iframe.html"></iframe>
<p>Test is after the iframe</p>
```

This is how you would style the iframe to have it cover the entire page. Note that there is no `.` before `iframe` in the CSS selector. `border: none` is important otherwise the iframe content would exceed the visible area.

```
iframe {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
}
```

See here an example: https://jsfiddle.net/c875zwda/

Comment: I've removed the div and applied your css. Still getting the same result.

Comment: @nimrodma What browser are you using?